# Superuser.com in lastest firefox is all text and not formatted?

Tags: firefox

I am wanting to use this site, but when I go to it using my main browser Firefox, it's all just text and no formatting.  But looks okay in IE and Chrome.   I get this here and there with Firefox, is there some setting I need to change?   The other stack sites look fine.  Right now the URL says https://superuser.com/questions/ask

Comment: Maybe stylesheets didn't load properly. Try `Ctrl`+`F5` to force a refresh.

Comment: Yeah, definitely sounds like the stylesheets aren't loading, which is usually a cache problem that the answer below solves.

Comment: If this is re-opened, it seems like a Meta thing I would think since it's SU specific, right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the latest Firefox myself and the site/formatting looks normal. Try using [CTRL+SHIFT+DEL] to bring up the 'Clear All History' menu and clear your cache. After doing this, reload the page and your browser should pull down a fresh copy of the style-sheets and relevant scripts.